# antiderivative of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having problems to show the implication ii) $\Rightarrow$ i).

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a connected open set, $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ an holomorpic function. Then we have equivalence between:

i) $f$ has a holomorphic antiderivative $F \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$

ii) for all loops $\gamma \colon [a, b] \to U $ which are piecewise differentiable, we have
$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 0$.

The direction from i) to ii) is clear:

i) $\Rightarrow$ ii):

Let's suppose $F = f'$ with $f$ holomorphic. So for all piecewise differentiable paths $\gamma \colon [a, b] \to U $, we have

$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = F( \gamma(b) ) - F( \gamma(a) )$,

which equals zero, because $\gamma$ is a closed path.

ii) $\Rightarrow$ i):

I suppose I have to show the following two things:

(a) the antiderivate is well-defined  // (b) the antiderivative is holomorphic

For (a):

Let $z_0 \in U$ be fixed, $z \in U$ any point and $\gamma_0$ a path, which connects $z_0$ with $z$. Then we have to show that

$F(z) = \int_{\gamma} f(w) dw$

is well-defined, i.e. does only depend on the point $z_0$ and $z$, but not on the choice of a specific path. Let $\gamma_1$ be another path from $z_0$ to $z$ and let's denote by $\gamma_1^{\ast}$ the path from $\gamma_1$, but gone through the opposite direction (from $z$ to $z_0$). Then $\gamma = \gamma_0 \circ \gamma_1^{\ast}$ is a loop and

$0 = \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{ \gamma_0 \circ \gamma_1^{\ast}} f(z) dz
= \int_{ \gamma_0 } f(z) dz - \int_{ \gamma_1^{\ast}} f(z) dz$

Is this correct? And how can I show part (b) ?

Comment: Correct so far. For (b), in $F(z+h) - F(z)$, use the path to $z$ followed by the straight line segment from $z$ to $z+h$ (assuming $\lvert h\rvert$ is sufficiently small).